# Place the balloon wherever click inside the Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

### **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/)**

I am trying to place the balloon wherever I click inside the Canvas. I can drag it easily but not able to place it at the click position

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
    var background = document.getElementById('background');
    var ballon = document.getElementById('ballon')
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

    $('#ballon').draggable();

    $('#draw').click(function() {
        var $ballon = $('#ballon'),
            $canvas = $('#canvas');
        var ballon_x = $ballon.offset().left - $canvas.offset().left,
            ballon_y = $ballon.offset().top - $canvas.offset().top;

        context.drawImage(ballon, ballon_x, ballon_y);

        $ballon.hide();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Inside your draw click function, you are getting the position of the balloon and not the position of the mouse click.

Comment: Is balloon positioned absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a quick and dirty positioning by using a `click` event on the Canvas like so:

```
$('#canvas').click(function ($event) {
        var $ballon = $('#ballon');

        $ballon.offset({
            left: $event.pageX - $ballon.width() / 2,
            top: $event.pageY - $ballon.height() / 2
        });

    });
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/8jAdJ/) to show it working.

**An alternative, and better way**, would be to use the [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/position/) utility method in jQuery UI to do the hard work for you.

Then your click method could look like this:

```
$('#canvas').click(function ($event) {
    var $ballon = $('#ballon');

    $ballon.position({
        of:$event,
        within:'#canvas',
        collision:'fit fit'
    });

});
```

Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/8jAdJ/2/) to show that example. Not that I am using [jQuery UI 1.9.2](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/) in order to take advantage of the `within: '#canvas'` option.

Comment: When you click on the canvas margin, Balloon goes out of the canvas.

Comment: @abcdefghi - If you really want to make sure things stay in place, then I would encourage you to use the jQuery UI `position` plugin. You can do much of what you want, while also making sure it stays bounded by another element. It takes care of all the hard work for you.

Comment: sure. any demo in this context will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Kalpers mentioned, you need to add a click handler on `#canvas` inside the click handler for `#draw`. Inside that click handler, you need to calculate the coordinates of the mouse when clicked. Right now, you don't know if the `canvas` element has been clicked.